# Usar usuário, e-mail ou um dos dois para a autenticação?

Tags: email, ux

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que, como todas as outras, precisará do e-mail do usuário para alguns fins. Cada usuário terá, também, um nome de usuário único para a página de seu perfil:

```
/u/:username
```

A questão é: durante o processo de autenticação (vulgo *login*), devo utilizar o **nome de usuário**, **e-mail** ou **um dos dois** (e-mail **ou** usuário)?

Pergunto isso por que para a minha aplicação, tanto faz. Mas fico na dúvida levando em conta que isso pode ter um leve impacto na experiência do usuário (principalmente de pessoas mais velhas, penso eu).

Ao analisar alguns sites, vejo que a maioria deles pede pede um dos dois, mas ainda gostaria de uma resposta. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se fala em experiência do usuário sempre tem que considerar quem é esse usuário. De acordo com cada tipo pode ser uma resposta diferente. Em geral costuma-se dizer que não dá para responder isso sem conduzir um experimento e avaliação criterioso para decidir o que é mais adequado.

Se quer mesmo uma forma generalizada e que pode não ser o melhor para o o seu usuário típico e mais importante, e que precisa de uma experiência mais adequada, então eu diria que permitir as duas formas parece melhor. Na verdade fico me perguntando porque faria diferente. Eu vejo só vantagens nisso, exceto que alguém pode se atrapalhar por ter opções, especialmente se os detalhes da implementação permitir isso.

Mas não é o fim do mundo hoje em dia ter uma só porque quase sempre a pessoa acessa usando auto preenchimento e não terá que lembrar ou ter esforço para colocar os dados ali. Claro, nem todos usam essa facilidade. Não esqueça de ter uma forma segura de recuperar o acesso por um destes dois. Em alguns casos pode ser interessante só aceitar o e-mail na recuperação para evitar perturbar usuários quando alguém tenta recuperar com um usuário de nome parecido.

Novamente, o que dará real experiência boa para o usuário não é essa decisão mas todos os detalhes de como será feito.

Alguma consideração que parece boba mas acho importante: "ambos" implica que os dois serão usados, é um **E**, e isso nem cogite, mas em seguida foi colocado "um ou outro" que é o oposto de ambos, então ok. Esses cuidados são importantes principalmente quando se fala de UX. A outra resposta coloca que deve ser "um **e** o outro", o que acho que só atrapalhara, por que faria isto? É uma complicação exigir os dois para ganho quase zero (tem uma ligeira vantagem de segurança, mas quase irrelevante). Pode ser que só foi dito isso por descuido já que depois ela diz o oposto.

Isso nada tem a ver com acessibilidade, tem só a ver com usabilidade, são conceitos distintos.

Comment: Yep. Realmente, o uso do "ambos" tornou a pergunta um pouco confusa. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela resposta. =)

Answer (score 2):

Para uma melhor experiência do usuário, seria interessante a pessoa acessar o sistema com os dois. E-mail e usuário! Digo isso por pura acessibilidade. Ao trabalhar apenas com usuário e senha, sem o e-mail, pode dificultar o acesso, principalmente quando a pessoa não acessa o sistema por algum tempo. Já com o e-mail isso pode diminuir, até porque é bem mais simples por na maioria das vezes sempre utilizarmos o mesmo e-mail. Além disso, tu dá mais opções para o usuário acessar o sistema. Não fica algo engessado. Outro ponto também, é quando a experiência é pelo celular. Para algumas pessoas pode ser interessante acessar o sistema via usuário por ter menos caracteres do que o e-mail. Já para alguns, o e-mail pode ser mais útil por ser mais fácil de lembrar. Só é importante colocar um placeholder ou um span alertando que o usuário pode logar das duas maneiras.

Acho muito interessante trabalhar utilizando o e-mail e o usuário. E para melhorar ainda mais a acessibilidade, seria legal outras opções, como login via facebook, google, github, etc... Ter opções à disposição é sempre muito bom.